# Use aimob-ng on Kali in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox

I can't use airmankib on Kali. I'm in VirtualBox. I keep getting

```
/stys/class/ieee80211 no such file or directory
```

when I use aimon-ng. How to fix so I can connect to the internet?

Comment: Did you mean airmon-ng? You spelled it incorrectly three times, and apparently misspelled the error message itself. That’s after Gilles corrected your other punctuation, spelling, and capitalization. If you don’t take care with your questions, they will not be received well.

Comment: Once you learn how to use it, make sure to learn how to type it because terminal doesn't autocorrect commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the Internet from Kali in VirtualBox. On most systems it will just work if you set up the virtual machine correctly. You need a NAT network interface in the virtual machine configuration.

You can't use wifi tools inside the virtual machine since the virtual machine doesn't have a wifi interface. Only the real machine has a wifi interface.

If you have a USB wifi adapter, then you can configure VirtualBox to let the virtual machine use access it *as a USB peripheral*. Then you use it normally as a wifi interface inside the virtual machine. You won't be able to use it in the real machine at the same time. With a non-USB adapter I don't think this is possible.